# writing own data reader for tensorflow producing tensors directly

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

I like to write a new data reader for tensorflow which produces multiple feature/label tensors directly w/o decoding the data from a string. I looked at the [new_data_formats](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/new_data_formats) tutorial yet I do not want my own reader class to interact through the interface

```
Status ReadLocked(string* key, string* value, bool* produced, bool* at_end)
```

since I am producing tensors directly. The reader should take a filename from a [filename queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) and produce multiple tensors (depending on the filesize) which are then enqueued into a [random batch queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch_join). My question is: From which class should my reader inherit to produce the tensors?  I think it is not sufficient to implement this simply as a [new op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) due to thread safety. I noticed that the [resource_op_kernel class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_op_kernel.h) maybe a suitable starting point.

Since this is quite deep inside tensorflow any pointers or additional hints where to start and what pitfalls may lie ahead are helpful (specifically some explanations about resource management, custom ops & thread-safety inside tensorflow).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the implementation of [tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/FixedLengthRecordDataset) would be a good place to start ([C++ op implementation here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/96caf514b79d2d74c7e1b1db8e9452473f5d9522/tensorflow/core/kernels/reader_dataset_ops.cc#L266)). That already takes a filename and returns Tensors directly, so it sounds like you'd just want to output several Tensors rather than one.

Granted that this is using [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) rather than queues. Probably a good idea regardless.